# Is it possible to redirect a domain that's referenced in code before it gets there?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In code, we're referencing "athirdpartydomain.com"

```
Page.Response.Redirect("www.athirdpartydomain.com");
```

However, the owners of "athirdpartydomain.com" have decided to change their domain.  This will involved a fairly considerable amount of work for us eventually, and they're letting the domain go completely.

We will of course change it in time, but I'm wondering if there's a quicker way to do this.  Like changing something on the server to make sure all requests to "athirdpartydomain.com" all go to "theirnewdomain.com"

Comment: are you hosting "www.athirdpartydomain.com"?

Comment: It amazes me that something so commonly used throughout your codebase wasn't a candidate for an external configuration (web config, database, etc).

Comment: ctrl+shift+H or buy the domain from them and put a re-direct there ;) Seriously though i have replaced domain and hosts like this its not too bad.. but replace it with a variable!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not hosting it no.  And it's only used once in the codebase, and does sit on a variable.  But it was never deemed to be something that would change...and even if it was sitting in a web.config somewhere, it's still going to be a lot of work to go through and change eeeevery site that's using it - which is a lot.  Hence the (somewhat desperate) attempt to do this server wide

Comment: Well, you can edit the hosts file of the server.. assuming you have access to it. That would be a habbit akin to putting a Band-Aid on a shotgun wound though.. so don't make it a habit.

Comment: Add it as a variable and then change the variable when needed

Comment: We'll upgrade everyone eventually...I do just need a band-aid style fix to tide us over.  How would changing the hosts file help though?

Comment: Oh god I haven't had a coffee. That won't help actually, since it's the client you're worrying about ... wow. Brain fart.

Comment: "and they're letting the domain go completely" can you buy/transfer it and add a redirect? Presumably you can communicate the technical issues arising from the client's move and agree a takeover?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're using .NET, I can imagine you're also using IIS and, so, you can do this using IIS Redirects. NB, this will only work if you're hosting www.athirdpartydomain.com and have access to the IIS on that server.

You can learn how to do this here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313074

Answer (score 0):

In .net you can't do that, but yes you can do that using cpanel of that domain.
You have to open that domain with admin login.

and you have to set "a name" or "a point" to particular server where you wants to redirect to site when some one browse the site this will redirect to particular site without load of that site.